# Assign ajax data val to table header

Tags: jquery

In my ajax call I want to assign each `key` as a `<td>` to a single row in the `$('#shelf .table thead tr')`. This is my attempt that is not working.

AJAX:

```
function ajax_call($aff){
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'fill_crosstab.php',                         
        data: {action:$aff},                                             
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(data){
            $('#shelf .table tbody').empty();

            $('#shelf .table thead tr').empty();
            for ( var i = 0; i < key.length; i++ ) {
                out += "<td>" + key[i] + "</td>"; 
            }
            $('#shelf .table thead tr').append(out + "</tr>");

            if ($aff == "database") {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    $('.dropdown-menu').append("<a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>" + val.Affiliation + "</a>");
                });
                    // Bind the event now, after the html element has bend created.
                $(".dropdown-menu a").on("click", function () {
                    var selText = $(this).text();
                    $('.shelf-header').empty();
                    $('.shelf-header').append(selText);
                    ajax_call(selText); 
                });
            } else {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    $('#shelf .table tbody').append("<tr><td>" + val.LAST + "</td><td>" + val.FIRST + "</td><td>" + val.MDC + "</td><td>" + val.RADIO + "</td><td>" + val.eMEDS + "</td><td>" + val.FireApp + "</td><td>" + val.P1 + "</td></tr>"); 
                });
            }
        }
    });
    };
```

JSON DATA:

```
[{"LAST":"JONE","FIRST":"MARY","MDC":"07\/23\/2003","RADIO":"08\/22\/2002","eMEDS":"02\/09\/2015","FireApp":"09\/11\/2012","P1":" "}]
```

Comment: Could you some sample data, and could you be more specific about how it is not working please?

Comment: added JSON data - I'm looking to get LAST, FIRST, MDC, ect... as the header row of my table.

Comment: Where is key defined for that first for loop? I can't see what that is here.

Comment: thats where I think i'm having the issue - I didn't want to put the `for loop` in the `.each` - do I need to add another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require the for loop to create the headers of the table, extracting the keys from the data, you will need to use the first row.

You should also retain the keys of that row to use to ensure that the other rows line up in the same columns. I note you use "." to get those as properties in the else clause at the bottom of that snippet.

Start by getting those keys - put this near the top of the success handler:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
```

Now you can loop over this to create your first row (put this in the thead section):

```
for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
    out += "<td>" + keys[i] + "</td>"; 
}
```

In that else section, the tbody, you can do this to make sure it matches up. This references that keys variable above, in the same order, and uses the key there to look up the value in the item:

```
$.each(data, function(_k, val) {
    var out = "<tr>";
    for( var i =0; i< keys.length; i++) {
       out += "<td>" + val[keys[i]] + "</td>";
    }
    out += "</tr>";
    $('#shelf .table tbody').append(out);
});
```

In this snippet here - the "_k" is the row number, I've prefixed it with an underscore to make it clear to a reader that we're not interested in it.

Comment: so where am I putting the `var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);` I see you are referencing both `key` and `keys` is this correct?

Comment: I've made edits to the answer. "key" has become "_k" - since it was something that the .each gives it that is ignored. I've also said where to put that first part.

Comment: this gives me the value of `LAST',`FIRST`etc... not the name `LAST` `FIRST` etc.

Comment: ok I changed `val[keys[i]]` to `keys[i]` and works.BUT... I'm getting header rows equal to results rows. in other words, I get 50 header rows...

Comment: `val` is important here - val is the actual row item data. Since each row item is an object, the key to look up the row item value comes from keys. So hence you should have `vals[keys[i]]` in the td's. However - I am not sure what you mean by your other comment - you'll need to explain that more.

Comment: I resolved - what should have been a single header row, was returning the same header row times the number of data rows. So if I have 5 rows of data , the header row returned 5 times.